# tty - write/read to uart script

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, uart, tty

I have a problem with **tty** (I am doing UART communication PC<->uC).

I send data to uC and its sends it back (echo).
I want to read and write to **tty**.

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 >output.txt & #redirect output to file and move to background
echo abcd > /dev/ttyUSB0       #write to tty
```

At the first run script works well. But if it is runned again, it skips characters, changes order etc. I have to unplug and plug usb (pl2303 Serial Port) to make the script work properly for one time.
I think it can be problem with synchronization or some buffers. Maybe there is a command to reset ttyUSB0 without unplugging it?

My uC sends data in 9600 8N1.

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a
speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt -echoctl -echoke
```

Thanks for help ;)

Comment: You can try writing a C program which uses read and write system calls on /dev/ttyUSB0.

Comment: *"cat /dev/ttyUSB0 >output.txt & #redirect output to file"*  -- You seem to have input/output backwards.  The data read from a device is called "input".  Try removing the uC from the test setup, and simply use a loopback in its place (i.e. connect the RS-232 RxD pin to the TxD pin).